# Cómo generar una entidad dinámicamente con los campos que contiene un geojson

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot

saludos a todos y ante todo dar las gracias a todos por intentar ayudarme.

Estoy utilizando SpringBoot (JPA + Hibernate) con mi back en Postgress.

Mi problema es que a partir de un fichero que subo a mi backend quiero que me genere una entidad de forma dinámica y la asocie a mi entidad shceme con cardinaliad 1 a 1.

El mayor problema es que cada fichero que suba tendrá campos diferentes que se tendrán que detectar al subir el fichero con su tipo.

En conclusión, la finalidad es que cuando suba un fichero se procese, obtenga las propiedades que serán los nombres de las columnas de la tabla y su correspondiente información y se asocie 1 a 1 con mi entidad scheme.

Este fichero [geojson](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/assets/earthquakes.geojson) de ejemplo tiene los siguientes campos:

- id
- mag
- time
- felt
- tsunami
- geometry

Tengo creado la entidad Scheme pero me falta como procesar esa información y crear dicha tabla dinámicamente.

Alguna idea?

```
@Entity(name = "Scheme")
@Table(name = "scheme")
@Access(AccessType.FIELD)
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@Accessors(chain = true)
public class Scheme extends BaseEntityActivable implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "SCHEME_SEQ_GEN")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "SCHEME_SEQ_GEN", sequenceName = "test_seq_scheme", allocationSize = 1)
    @Column(name = "scheme_id")
    private Long schemetId;

    @Column(name = "file_name", nullable = false, updatable = false)
    @NotEmpty(message = ErrorConstants.FILE_PATH_CANT_BE_EMPTY)
    @Field(analyze = Analyze.NO, store = Store.YES)
    private String fileName;

    @Column(name = "original_file_name", nullable = false, updatable = false)
    @NotEmpty(message = ErrorConstants.FILE_NAME_CANT_BE_EMPTY)
    @Field(analyze = Analyze.NO, store = Store.YES)
    private String originalFileName;

    @Column(name = "extension")
    @Field(analyze = Analyze.NO, store = Store.YES)
    @Facet(encoding = FacetEncodingType.STRING)
    private String extension;

    @Column(name = "filesize")
    @Field(analyze = Analyze.NO, store = Store.YES)
    private Long filesize;
}
```